# iOS: setImageWithURLRequest without cropping image

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a viewController that contains an UIImageView. I want to present it using aspect fill like this:

[image]

I also want the user to be able to tap the image to get a full screen image with the correct aspect ratio. However, it seems like the setImageWithURLRequest method is altering the UIImage itself before it is returned in the success block. Here's the code I'm using to display the image:

```
    [coverImage setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://XXXXXXXXXX/index.aspx?isbn=%@/lc.gif&client=XXXXXXX",coverImage.isbn]]] placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

        [coverImageSpinner stopAnimating];
        [coverImageSpinner setHidden:YES];
        if (image.size.height>1) {
            CGImageRef newCgIm = CGImageCreateCopy(image.CGImage);
            UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newCgIm scale:image.scale orientation:image.imageOrientation];
            originalImage=newImage;
            if (detailPaneFocused) {
                [UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:.33f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
                    coverImage.image=image;
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                }];
            }else{
                    coverImage.image=image;
            }


        }else{
            coverImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"book_fixed"];
        }
```

So I'm trying to make a copy of the original image before it gets cropped for aspect fill, but this doesn't work:

[image]

Is there a way to grab the actual downloaded image before it gets cropped based on the UIImageView's content mode?

Thanks!

EDIT: I tried the suggestion below, but strangely it's still not working. Here's the code that downloads the image:

```
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.syndetics.com/index.aspx?isbn=%@/lc.gif&client=260-421-1200",coverImage.isbn]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *downloadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    [coverImageSpinner stopAnimating];
    [coverImageSpinner setHidden:YES];
    if (downloadedImage.size.height>1) {
        CGImageRef newCgIm = CGImageCreateCopy(downloadedImage.CGImage);
        originalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newCgIm scale:downloadedImage.scale orientation:downloadedImage.imageOrientation];
        if (detailPaneFocused) {
            [UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:.33f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
                coverImage.image=downloadedImage;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            }];
        }else{
            coverImage.image=downloadedImage;
        }


    }else{
        coverImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"book_fixed"];
    }
```

And here's the method that's called when the image is tapped. I'm still getting the cropped image. Does it have to do with the bounds I'm setting since it's in landscape orientation?

```
if(originalImage!=nil){
    UIViewController *modalCon = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    modalCon.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    modalCon.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;



    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:modalCon.view.bounds];
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

    [imageView setImage:originalImage];

    [imageView setCenter:self.view.center];
    [modalCon.view addSubview:imageView];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *modalTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissModalView)];
    [modalCon.view addGestureRecognizer:modalTap];
    modalCon.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:modalCon animated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"%f",modalCon.view.frame.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"%f",modalCon.view.frame.origin.x);
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating `newImage` and `originalImage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:modalCon.view.bounds];
```

This gave the UIImageView a portrait size (greater height than width) even though the app is locked in landscape mode. By simply swapping the width and height of the UIImageView, I get the correct appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could always grab the raw image before you use the setImage method :

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your URL"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, that's pretty obvious. Is there a way to do that asynchronously with blocks like I'm doing above?

Comment: I'd suggest using NSOperation as you'll probably find you want to cancel larger image downloads if the user exits the screen.